# Can not execute raw sql 'UPDATE ...' during rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my rake task I have such connection

```rb
def some_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({ adapter:  'mysql2', 
                                            host:     'localhost', 
                                            username: Rails.application.secrets.etalon_db_username, 
                                            password: Rails.application.secrets.etalon_db_password, 
                                            database: 'somedb' })
                    .connection
end
```

And I need to execute this sql instruction

```sql
UPDATE car_generation SET year_end = 0 WHERE id_car_generation IN (292,488,1663,6542)
```

Running this:

```rb
some_connection.exec_update(fix_query, nil, [])
```

i get the error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: NoMethodError: undefined method `query' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  to_query: UPDATE car_generation
SET year_end = 0
WHERE id_car_generation IN (292,488,1663,6542...)
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/gems/activerecord-4.1.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/gems/activerecord-4.1.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:378:in `block in log'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/gems/activesupport-4.1.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/gems/activerecord-4.1.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:372:in `log'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/gems/activerecord-4.1.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/gems/activerecord-4.1.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:228:in `execute'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/gems/activerecord-4.1.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:255:in `exec_delete'
lib/tasks/etalon_db_tables_population.rake:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
lib/tasks/etalon_db_tables_population.rake:10:in `each'
lib/tasks/etalon_db_tables_population.rake:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@gemset/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

The same error appears when I use **execute** instead of **exec_query**.

But everything is ok if I execute this code during Rails migration.

Comment: Use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(fix_query)`

Comment: __execute__ produces the same error

Comment: Instead of using `  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...)` you should try to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(fix_query)`

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.connection takes connection parameters from *database.yml* according to Rails.env but I need to connect to another database so i use *....establish_connection(...).connection*

Comment: @Igor can you please add you full rake task. Also don't you think it would be easy to do `ActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on stack trace for ActiveRecord 4.1.13, [sources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb) shows, that `@connection` is `nil`.

So, you need to test your `some_connection` method - most probably it returns `nil`. And then investigate, why you couldn't connect to DB.